# Create AWS sagemaker endpoint and delete the same using AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

Is there a way to create sagemaker endpoint using AWS lambda ?

The maximum timeout limit for lambda is 300 seconds while my existing model takes 5-6 mins to host ?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to combine Lambda and Step functions with a wait state to create sagemaker endpoint

In the step function have tasks to

1 . Launch AWS Lambda to CreateEndpoint

```
import time
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

endpoint_name = 'DEMO-imageclassification-' + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", time.gmtime())
endpoint_config_name = 'DEMO-imageclassification-epc--2018-06-18-17-02-44'
print(endpoint_name)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    create_endpoint_response = client.create_endpoint(
        EndpointName=endpoint_name,
        EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name)
    print(create_endpoint_response['EndpointArn'])
    print('EndpointArn = {}'.format(create_endpoint_response['EndpointArn']))

    # get the status of the endpoint
    response = client.describe_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
    status = response['EndpointStatus']
    print('EndpointStatus = {}'.format(status))
    return status
```

2 . Wait task to wait for X minutes

3 . Another task with Lambda to check EndpointStatus and depending on EndpointStatus (OutOfService | Creating | Updating | RollingBack | InService | Deleting | Failed) either stop the job or continue polling

```
import time
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

endpoint_name = 'DEMO-imageclassification-2018-07-20-18-52-30'
endpoint_config_name = 'DEMO-imageclassification-epc--2018-06-18-17-02-44'
print(endpoint_name)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # print the status of the endpoint
    endpoint_response = client.describe_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
    status = endpoint_response['EndpointStatus']
    print('Endpoint creation ended with EndpointStatus = {}'.format(status))

    if status != 'InService':
        raise Exception('Endpoint creation failed.')


    # wait until the status has changed
    client.get_waiter('endpoint_in_service').wait(EndpointName=endpoint_name)


    # print the status of the endpoint
    endpoint_response = client.describe_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
    status = endpoint_response['EndpointStatus']
    print('Endpoint creation ended with EndpointStatus = {}'.format(status))

    if status != 'InService':
        raise Exception('Endpoint creation failed.')

    status = endpoint_response['EndpointStatus']
  return
```

[image]

Another approach is to combination of AWS Lambda functions and CloudWatch rules which I think would be clumsy.

Comment: We can use wait task but lambda timeout is 5 mins and endpoint creation is  taking 5-6 mins . Thus the Lambda giving timeout error

Comment: How to use cloud-watch rule ? I could not find SageMaker option in a services drop down while creating a rule in cloud-watch

Comment: I have updated answer with the code. CreateEndpoint is async call which just returns ARN of the endpoint. In the second lambda, you will implement the poller that can check the status of the endpoint creation. In step function, you will add wait time.

Comment: Also CloudFormation (CFN) now supports SageMaker and you can create an endpoint through CFN.

Answer (score 0):

While rajesh answer is closer to what the question ask for, I like to add that sagemaker now has a batch transform job.

Instead of continously hosting a machine, this job can handle predicting large size of batches at once without caring about latency. So if the intention behind the question is to deploy the model for a short time to predict on a fix amount of batches. This might be the better approach.

Comment: Main purpose is to automate endpoint creation part on demand Programmatically. So is there any way to do it ?

Comment: It depends how you want to use your model. The batch_transform_job does not need an endpoint. So there is no need for waiting for its creation. It creates an endpoint itself and feed the predefined data for invocation. If it's done with it, it shuts down automatically.

Comment: I agree with dennis-ec here. If your requirement is to perform a batch predictions then the new feature Batch Transform would be ideal and endpoint is provisioned/destroyed by itself. Note that, only S3 as input is supported as of now.